# Making raw_input read from a file

Tags: python, file, stdin

I'm trying to test some script which uses `raw_input`, I have some predefined input files where each line is the appropriate input.
E.g

input.txt:

```
y
n
y
...
```

I'm trying to replace `sys.stdin` with a file object but something is wrong.

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    sys.stdin = f
    con = raw_input("aaa") # in reality this is a function which somewhere calls raw_input
    print con # prints nothing 
    sys.stdin = old # saved earlier
```

I want the function which calls `raw_input` to get the input from the file rather then the `stdin`.
I have several such files and I want to loop over then and report accordingly. E.g in this example I'd like `con` to contain `'y'`

But obviously:

```
with open("advanced_test1.in") as f:
    print f.read()
```

prints the file's content as expected.

Comment: can u explain more wt you wanat to do>>

Comment: @Hackaholic I've tried to add more details

Answer (score 3):

When executing the file, use the `<` operator as follows:

```
python myfile.py < input.txt
```

Comment: I'm aware of that but I also need to pass a variable to that function (which calls `raw_input`) that's why I want to replace the `stdin` and not just use `<`